# Jumps to top of screen on Click in React (MUI) on Trident+

Tags: internet-explorer-11, outlook-web-addins

On most clicks (example on a button, or on a delete icon, or "ok" to close the calendar), the screen "jumps all the way to the top in an instant.  This is extremely annoying and confusing for the user.

We have narrowed down this issue to only occurring on Outlook instances using Trident+ ([that is on Outlook volume licesed 2013, 2016, 2019 as well as a few others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins)).

Trident+ is mostly IE11, but with some additional things which are not really clear.

You can see a video of this issue here:https://youtu.be/9r62bhP-FrI

We expect the viewable part of the screen not to jump to the top upon most clicks.

We haven't really tried anything yet since we don't even know where to start on this.  It has been a journey to even find out about Trident+.  If I am right, the docuementation was updated at least in part because I pointed out where information was missing on what browser exactly is being used in which outlook version.